# How do i build service send/receive sms by asp.net

Tags: asp.net, service, sendmessage

I need to build service send/receive sms by asp.net. I find out some website or company provider that service. But it's not properly for my job. My problems are: how do i build my own service to do that? what i need to do? SMS gateway is a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need the following.

1. Web service to allow other application to send their messages along
   with the destination number. Which would put the message in database.
2. Windows application could be a windows service to get the messages
   from database and send them using attached gsm modem. This
   codeproject [**article**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20420/How-To-Send-and-Receive-SMS-using-GSM-Modem) gives you idea to start communication
   with gsm modems using serial port.

Comment: I get it. Thanks Adil so much.